# Quicksort worst case with middle as pivot

Tags: runtime, big-o, quicksort

I am a little bit confused,

I tried to understand which arrays would be the worst case scenario for quicksort (chatgpt contradicted itself several and I have no clue.) (new to cs)

I thought that it would be a sorted array because it will need to divide it to units but i tried manually and it wasn't n^2

Answer (score 0):

Sorted array with no duplicates is a best case O(n log(n)) when using middle element for pivot for either Lomuto or Hoare partition scheme. For an array with lots or all duplicates it's the worst case for Lomuto partition scheme, and best case for Hoare partition scheme.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements

Otherwise a worst case data pattern depends on which scheme is used and always ending up with the middle element being the smallest or largest value.